# Webpack 4 Incorrectly Rendering Select Element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, webpack, webpack-4

I have a simple `select` element that for some reason is not being rendered properly by Webpack. The image below my HTML shows the final rendered page source, where the closing tag for the `select` element has been moved up and placed before the `option` elements. I have not been able to find any documented cases of what could cause this.

```html
<select name="language" id="language">
  <optgroup label="Select Language">
    <option value="all" selected>All Languages</option>
    <option value="german" lang="de">Englisch Deutsch</option>
    <option value="french" lang="fr">Anglais français</option>
    <option value="italian" lang="it">Inglese e italiano</option>
    <option value="spanish" lang="es">Ingles Espa&#241;ol</option>
    <option value="english" lang="en">English Only</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image: select element rendered HTML]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into something similar, the problem was related to the webpack minify settings. The `html5` property needed a value of `true`.

```js
const minify = {
  html5: true,
  // ...
}
```